# how to compile res_srtp.c in asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

I have a problem to add the module res_srtp to my asterisk.
In fact, when I do "module show" in the asterisk console, I don't find the file res_srtp.so in the module list.
I tried to do "gcc -shared res_srtp.c -o res_srtp.so -lsrtp" but it doesn't work! 
it says: fatal error: srtp/srtp.h no such file is found.
How to compile it please.

Answer (score 0):

Libsrtp is a dependency for this module. You need to install that first. If you install it from a package don't forget to install the libsrtp-devel package as well. If you want to compile it, here is the source:
http://srtp.sourceforge.net/srtp.html